# Why won't it recognize an invalid selection from my dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I'm trying to display a message to the user if they decide not to choose an item from the dropdown menu using strictly vanilla JS.  Instead, I get an error in the console that says `cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of null`.  I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

How can I rectify this problem?

Here's HTML:

```
        <form>
            <div>
                <label>Drop Down Menu
                    <select name="menu">
                        <option value="">---</option>
                        <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
                        <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Here's JS:

```
var myForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
myForm.id = "the-form";

var submitButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1];
submitButton.id = "submit-button";

function formValidation() {    
    var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    select.id = "myMenu";

    var selectId = document.getElementById("myMenu");
    if(selectId.selectedIndex <= 0) {
        console.log("a menu item must be selected!");
    }

    alert("Chosen!");
}

submitButton.onclick = myForm.onsubmit = function() {
    formValidation();
};
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of element, not a single one.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting a DOM node by the id of "myMenu" here:

```
 var selectId = document.getElementById("myMenu");
```

while the select you want to target has id "menu". Therefore, you have to change either the id in the JS selection or the select's id in the html.